# How to get the number of occurrences of a certain character on the current line in Vim?

Tags: counting

Using Vim 8. I want to count the number of pipe symbols that are on the current line so that I can compare it to the other lines in the file and make sure my pipe symbol count is consistent. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count occurrences by search/replace without actual change with `n` option.

```
:s,|,,gn
```